# How to find unused endpoints on Spring REST application running on Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, splunk

We are running our Spring applications on Tomcat, and over a period of time we have added multiple REST endpoints to our application. We now want to trim it down and remove all the unused endpoints that our GUIs do not use any more.

We do use Splunk, but it will only give the number of hits on active endpoints from the log aggregator on localhost_access file of Tomcat. We want to find the end points that have 0 hits.

The most straightforward way is to write some kind of python script, that copies data from Tomcat start up, and gets all the end points(or manually feed it). Then put them in a hash map, and then go over local host access files in Tomcat server logs for last few months, incrementing a counter when the corresponding endpoint is met. Then print out all the keys in this hash map with value 0.

Is the above a feasible way to do so, or does there exist an easier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splunk is essentially a search engine and, like any other search engine, cannot find something that is not there.  Endpoints with no hits will not have data in Splunk and so will not appear in search results.

The usual approach to a problem like this is to start with a list of known objects and subtract those that are found by Splunk.  The result is a list of unused objects.  You touched on this concept yourself with your hash map idea.

Create a CSV file containing a list of all of your endpoints.  I'll call it endpoints.csv.  Then use it in a search like this one:

```
index=foo endpoint=* NOT [ inputlookup endpoint.csv | format ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to find unused endpoints, go to access.log, check for few days logs which all endpoints are getting accessed. You'll get to know, which endpoints are unused over a period of time.

Comment: could you please elaborate how is your solution scalable. I am trying to understand how you can manually track hundreds of endpoints; accounting for no human error.